# Nginx | All subdomains webmmail.*.* to one document root

Tags: nginx

Beforehand i want to note that I have looked around on Nginx wiki. Stackoverflow and Servervault before asking here.

I have trouble with my nginx config. This is my config

```
server {
    listen 8080;
    root /opt/apanel/apps/webmail;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    server_name webmail.*.*;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~* \.php$ {
        fastcgi_index   index.php;
        fastcgi_pass    unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        include         fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

I want all webmail subdomains to show oint to one document root.

The line from my Error log:

^[[1;5A2014/07/20 19:44:41 [emerg] 9276#0: invalid server name or wildcard "admin.*.*" on 0.0.0.0:8080

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From nginx's [docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html):

> A wildcard name may contain an asterisk only on the name’s start or end, and only on a dot border. The names `www.*.example.org` and `w*.example.org` are invalid. However, these names can be specified using regular expressions, for example, `~^www\..+\.example\.org$` and `~^w.*\.example\.org$`

You will need to use a regular expression match for your server_name, such as:

```
server_name ~^webmail\..*\..*$;
```

Comment: Thank you. Coming from Apache i did not know about the regex and will remember for future use. This helped me a lot.